# google map with multiple routes - auto zoom and center map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, zooming, centering

I have managed to modify a script I found to suite my needs.

my only current issue is that I have to set the center of the map manually in the code and the zoom level.

how can I modify this so the api automatically selects the correct zoom level and center point for the map.

fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anBYW/1/)

I need to remove this manual code:

```
var map    = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-30.559, 22.937),
                  zoom: 4
               }),
```

and configure it to zoom and center automatically based on the routes given (routes array)

you will see in the fiddle that the costa rica route is off the map so zoom needs to go out. if it was a short trip then zoom in to fit all contents into the map

Thanks as always:

Comment: check it this page : http://jsfiddle.net/cRdyd/1/ You need to control your draw function. May you need to add getPosition() after your function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get rid of that code. Option `center` and `zoom` are the only **required** parameters of `google.maps.MapOptions` object. See docs [of MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions).

You can get rid of option `preserveViewport` or set it to `false` instead of `true` so your map will be centered and properly zoomed.

Comment: I think this is the way to go although you could also create a bounds object, extend it with each route start and end coordinates then do a `map.fitBounds();` with your bounds object. This way you could *bypass* the center and zoom options.